# apt autoremove and autoclean without root

Tags: apt, sudo

Is it possible to run apt housekeeping commands (`apt-get autoremove`, `apt-get autoclean`) without root user, by granting permission of executing apt/apt-get to a user instead.

It seems that you have to use root/sudo to execute those commands, otherwise it would fail:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers
...
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
user  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
user  ALL= (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get 

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
user  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

$ /usr/bin/apt-get autoremove
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, most `apt-get` commands need to be run as root, including `autoremove` and `autoclean`. With your configuration, that means

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Note that allowing users to run any `apt-get` command as root is effectively the same as giving them full root access. (The user can prepare a package and install it; the package can contain anything the user wants, including a root-suid shell. Another option is to arrange for `dpkg` to encounter a configuration file conflict, in which case it can be asked to open a root shell.) To avoid this risk, you should fully specify the commands in `sudoers`:

```
user  ALL= (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get autoremove
user  ALL= (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get autoclean
```

At least for `autoclean`, you may find it useful to set up a cron job instead.

Comment: I am using zabbix account (non-root) to trigger `apt-get autoremove` when disk alert occurs. but so far, even if I gave execution of `apt-get autoremove` (`zabbix ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get autoremove`), it still does not work. The error is still `Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)`

Comment: You need to run `sudo apt-get autoremove`, not `apt-get autoremove`.